# Multithreaded solution (instead of multiprocesses) for reporting server

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, server, jxcore

**NodeJS** is **still not multi-threading** after those many years since first release. **JXCore** is multi-threading but **dead**. I need **multi-threaded JS server** for my project, any solution?

NodeJS cluster mode can't solve my problem as my server has reporting API, 4 heavy reporting requests from client-side can hang the whole 4 CPUs of my server.

It should better slow down all requests rather than having capability to serve 4 heavy requests only.

Comment: You might want to try actor model or use child_process library

Comment: If your Node.js application is able to consume all the resources of your hardware, you don't need to restructure your application, you need more hardware.

Comment: @brad, i want all requests run slow instead of the fifth one stuck

Comment: @Malice, process-based workers eat RAM just like CGI

Comment: i hate downvoting on a serious question, downvoters, shewshew

Comment: @johnlowvale Then run more instances of your Node.js app... you don't even need the cluster module for this, but yes, that will solve your problem if the problem can be solved at the application level.  You haven't told us anything about what your work load is, so for all we know, you might be locked at a database or something.

Comment: @johnlowvale I downvoted your question because you're making a bunch of assumptions and providing no useful information to actually help you get a useful answer.  If you were literally asking about future release features in Node.js and V8, then your question would be off-topic for Stack Overflow.  But, I suspect you actually want a solution to your problem instead.

Comment: @brad, more instances (ie. more processes) mean duplicated binaries in RAM, multi-threading is different

Comment: @johnlowvale Doubtful you're going to save a whole lot of system resources through threading.  Node.js itself doesn't use much memory at all.  Also, you do realize that many of the libraries used in Node applications actually are threaded?  The only thing single threaded is your main JavaScript loop.  Why don't you make a native module for the parts you think require threading?  Alternatively, you can use worker threads... but again, it sounds to me like you're having no problems consuming your hardware, so you're coming at the problem sideways.

Comment: V8 uses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libuv which has a thread pool for doing multi threading, you could write a module which exploits this

Comment: yeah, write a native module myself for multithreading, but then the project is not fully JS anymore, nevermind, JS+C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJS does support multi-threading via the `child_process` API.

You can use `child_process.fork` to spawn new threads running a specific js module and opens an IPC communications channel to pass data back and forth between them.

[Documentation here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)

Comment: fork creates new process, not thread "Each process has its own memory, with their own V8 instances"  https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options